# External stylesheet not working in IE 10 and Mozilla FIrefox

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
        body { background: blue; }
        * { color: red; }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1 id="1">
                    Das haben sie ausgewält
            </h1>
            <h2>
                Diese Seite stellt ein Inhaltsverzeichniss und Index für Bücher aller Arten
                <br>
                Außerdem erfolgt eine kurze Vorstellung dieser Bücher mit dazugehörigen Cover nach diesem Muster:
            </h2>
          </center>
            <h3>
                <div id ="02">
                    <div id="01">
                        Hier wird die kurze Inhaltsangabe sowie Informationen zum Author stehen.
                    </div>
                    <div id="03">
                       <img src="buchregal.jpg" alt="Computer Man" style="width:805px;height:465px;"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h3>
    </body>
```

This Code is working but upon putting the css into a stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formate.css">
```

It suddenly stops working. Both my HTML and formate.css are in the same folder. I think it may be browser related but I am not sure. I have tried other posts but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you check the file is loaded checking "page source"? Did you clear cache?

Comment: Try `ctrl + f5`. If it is still not working. It's the path of the file.

Comment: @LaraBelle It's still not working I checked it the problem occured onece I loaded it from another PC to my Laptop which has different browsers.

Comment: Does it give any error in console? Is that the only css content in the file?

Comment: @Harikrishnan N where can I clean cache?

Comment: Run `location.reload(true)` in console to clear cache.

Comment: @ Juan Ferrerass in IE 10 it isn't in console and in Mozilla it works now eventough I changed nothing. No there is more contend in the css file.

Comment: Is your css file named "formate.css"? Or "format.css"?

Comment: Are you putting the `<style>` tags in the CSS file?

Comment: It is called formate.css and no there are no <style> tags